# Form reset after submission Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Creating a simple contact form here. I have created states for the input fields as seen below

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [messages, setMessage] = useState('')
```

My handleSubmit function that pushes the data to the database.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  db.collection("contacts")
      .add({
        fullName: fullName,
        email: email,
        selecttype : selecttype ,
        message: message,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("message has been submitted");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  setFullName('')
  setEmail('')
  setMessage('')
}
```

This is how I used the state in the form.(left out message and email fields since they have the same onChange function as fullName.)

```
<FormContent>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Icon to="/">
                <img src={dLogo} />
              </Icon>
              <FormH1>Fill in your request details below</FormH1>
              <FormLabel value="fullName">
                Full Name <RequiredTag>*</RequiredTag>
              </FormLabel>
              <FormInput
                type="text"
                name="fullName"
                onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
              />

              ...
              <FormLabel value="services">
                What would you wants to do for you?
                <RequiredTag>*</RequiredTag>
              </FormLabel>
              <select
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const selectedOption = e.target.value;
                  setSelectType(selectedOption);
                  console.log(selectedOption);
                }}
              >
                <option>Select ...</option>
                <option value="webSolutions">Web Solutions</option>
                <option value="mobileSolutions">Mobile Solutions</option>
                <option value="devOps">DevOps Solutions</option>
                <option value="research">Research Assistance</option>
                <option value="uiux">UI/UX Design</option>
              </select>
              ...
              <FormButton type="submit">
                Submit Request
              </FormButton>
              
            </Form>
          </FormContent>
```

Why don't the form fields reset after a successful submission?

Comment: “Isn't this supposed to reset my form to the initial state and empty the form fields?”  - Depends what you do with those state variables. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: `useState` prevents a function from being functional. The alternative to class components are *function* components, not *functional* components.

Comment: Try putting your setState code inside a ".finally" but yeah I agree you should should be more specific. But what I think is happening is that the code for setState is never executed. Or you are not using the hooks correctly so even after setting state the compenent is not updating, this could be the case for that call. You can also try making this update inside an useEffect

Comment: If there is *some* issue with a form then you should most certainly include your form component/elements as part of a relevant code example. How is the form rendering the inputs that need to be reset? What debugging have you done other than note that "it's not working"? I don't see an issue specifically with the code you've shared, but what it does depends on all the other code around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think as @Ricador Silva mentioned, you should run a 'finally' to make whatever you need to run (regardless of the outcome from the promise).

```
.then(() => ...//something to do if promise is successful)
.catch(e => ...//some error handling when promise fails)
.finally(() => ...//something you want to do whether or not the promise is successful, some clean-up)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Also, for your input values, the values should be:

```
<input type="text" values={fullName} />
```

currently, you just have `name="fullName"` for your FormInput component.

Read more about forms in react here:
controlled components vs uncontrolled components
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: I have added my setState to the .finally  but it still does not do anything.


`.finally(()=> {
 setFullName(' '),
 setEmail(' '),
 setMessage(' '),
 setSelectType([]),
})`

Comment: did you try to read the doc about input forms in react? if you're handling input form state with React, you need to use controlled input. Right now your input is missing it's value
`<FormInput  type="text"  name="fullName"  onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}  />`
this needs to have a value attribute, as with others

`<FormInput type="text"   name="fullName"  value={fullName} onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}/>`

Comment: Thanks and yes, I did and I did add the values to my inputs.

Comment: The state updates are ***outside*** the promise chain, they'll happen regardless of the outcome of the Promise chain. The Promise chain is irrelevant in the provided code snippet.

Comment: Hey guys, I found the solution. I just used the reset function in react hook forms like so 
`const {
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });`

Then I called it after submit:
`const onSubmit = (data) => {
   console.log(data)
      reset()
  }`

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You've quasi-controlled inputs, meaning you've attached an `onChange` handler (like one would with fully-controlled inputs), but you've not specified a `value` prop (like one would with fully-uncontrolled inputs).

## Solution

Either add the `value` prop so the inputs are fully controlled. When reset the state the input's value is ***controlled*** and you will see the reset values.

```
<FormInput
  type="text"
  name="fullName"
  value={fullName} // <-- control the input's value
  onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Or since the inputs are *technically* uncontrolled, use the form's `onSubmit` event object to reset the form. Here you can also just access the forms field values and remove the local component state.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const fullName = e.target.fullName.value;
  const email = e.target.email.value;
  const selecttype = e.target.selecttype.value; // <-- would need to set input name attribute
  const message = e.target.message.value;

  e.target.reset(); // <-- call the form's reset function

  db.collection("contacts")
    .add({
      fullName,
      email,
      selecttype,
      message,
    })
    .then(() => {
      alert("message has been submitted");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
}
```